# How to initiate a Windows Service from a COBOL Mainframe

Tags: windows-services, cobol, mainframe

We have a Windows Service running on one of our servers on premises. There is a business requirement to initiate/start this WinService from a mainframe that uses/runs COBOL based applications.

The requirements is perhaps vague but in essence we need to have a COBOL program(script?) that can talk to our server and start this service.

How do I get started on this ?

Comment: Are you using "scheduling" on Windows already? I'd transfer a "trigger" file from the Mainframe and have your Windows Scheduler monitor a directory and start whatever you want when the trigger arrives.

Comment: Thanks Bill - the Windows Service runs on startup and uses polling (polls some location every 10min ) to carry out whatever it needs to do. I suppose the same can be extended to monitor this "trigger" file location.

Any pointers on how to send a "trigger" file from the COBOL main frame ?

Comment: For the mechanism, find out what transfer software is available (like ftp, sftp, Connect:Direct, etc) then have a scheduled or tiggered JOB on the Mainframe which runs the transfer.In the trigger itself I'd include business/data date, logical trigger name, environment (dev-testing, sys-testing, Production, etc) and then check all those when the trigger is received, so you have less chance to shoot yourself in the foot,

Comment: In our project there are jobs that run script on unix using Connect:Direct. I assume that you can do the same thing over windows.

Comment: Thank you Bill and Abend ... what Bill said is right, I got hold of a team that was managing this main frame previously and the same idea is being kicked around.. I will check with ConnectDirect on Windows.

Comment: You could also make the windows scheduler run a batch script to check if new file is present on mainframe using ftp. It would be easier than setting up ConnectDirect on windows.